# How to read & update a mongodb collection using python 2.7?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, amazon-s3

I’m trying to connect to the mongo db and update the collection, my use case is:- 
Search the collection with a particular runid/batchid, if it is found then insert a new column as “Status” and value = “complete for that document."
Here is an array of run_ids:

```
144019800231859
144019800231659
144222840203400
144019800231559
144019800231759
144019800231459
144019080231459
144223560212920
144222120225005
```

This is how my collection looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("537d171c2273d16335000001"),
"file" : "/data/raw/xact/logs/edw/*/xxxx8835/ex14052114.log.gz",
"created_at" : 1400706844,
"batch_id" : NumberLong(1400706390198590000),
"run_id" : NumberLong(140070639019859)
}
```

So, if I find a run_id from my list in the collection then I want to add one more column to the collection. So final output should look like this.

```
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("537d171c2273d16335000001"),
    "file" : "/data/raw/xact/logs/edw/*/qaz02htp8835/noarchive/ex14052114.log.gz",
    "created_at" : 1400706844,
    "batch_id" : NumberLong(1400706390198590000),
    "run_id" : NumberLong(140070639019859)
    “Status” : “complete" 
   }
```

Can anyone please help me achieve this?

Here is what I have written so far.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient # Comes with pymongo
client = MongoClient('mongodb://user:hadoop_qa@localhost.corp.homestore.net:33307/')
db = client['jobs_qa']
collection = db['export_batch_tracker']
print collection
```

Answer (score 0):

**Notes:**

Loop through the given ids and **`set status ="Complete"`** where run id matches

You could do the same thing for batch_id

**Code:**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient # Comes with pymongo
client = MongoClient('mongodb://user:hadoop_qa@localhost.corp.homestore.net:33307/')
db = client['jobs_qa']
collection = db['export_batch_tracker']
run_ids=[144019800231859,144019800231659,144222840203400,144019800231559,144019800231759,144019800231459,144019080231459,144223560212920,144222120225005]
for ids in run_ids:
    collection.update({"run_id":ids},{"$set":{"Status":"Complete"}})
```

Comment: error message is displayed `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users//GitRepos/Log-Ship/Log-Ship/log_ship_run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/GitRepos/Log-Ship/Log-Ship/log_ship_run.py", line 33, in <module>
    collection.update({"batch_id":ids},{"$set":{"Status":"Complete"}})
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1956, in update
    with self._socket_for_writes() as sock_info:
  File`

Comment: `File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 54, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(response_doc, msg, allowable_errors)
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 188, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'user'), ('nonce', u'f1cf8ee7a00896df'), ('key', u'1cd20f7606e071d2291a1330053be710')]) on namespace admin.$cmd failed: auth fails`

Comment: @Guddi you user name and password is wrong from the given message you showed try connecting using cmd prompt

Comment: `File "/Users/sshirke/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 188, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'user'), ('nonce', u'ed21c07e7275b032'), ('key', u'419b85a846bd341f98f74e58c1ff793c')]) on namespace admin.$cmd failed: auth fails
`